# Error refreshing the OAuth2 token { "error" : "invalid_grant" }

Tags: google-api-php-client

please help me to understand where mistake.

**API**

Google Api PHP v3, key.p12 is the file in the .zip collection API (or where i find it ?)

I masked my data with xxxxxxxxxx

Excuse me for my inglish

**gaphp.php**

```
<?php

      require_once 'Google/Client.php';
      require_once 'Google/Service/Analytics.php';

      $client_id = 'xxx-xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
      $service_account_name = 'xxx-xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
      $keyfile = 'key.p12';
      $redirect_url = 'http://example.com/service/ga/gaphp.php';
      $client_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

      // Initialise the Google Client object
      $client = new Google_Client();
      $client->setApplicationName('My application');
      $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_url);
      $client->setClientSecret($client_secret);

      $client->setAssertionCredentials(
              new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
                  $service_account_name,
                  array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics'),
                  file_get_contents($keyfile)
              )
      );

      // Get this from the Google Console, API Access page
      $client->setClientId($client_id);
      $client->setAccessType('offline_access');
      $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

      // We have finished setting up the connection,
      // now get some data and output the number of visits this week.

      // Your analytics profile id. (Admin -> Profile Settings -> Profile ID)
      $analytics_id   = 'ga:xxxxxx';
      $lastWeek       = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 week'));
      $today          = date('Y-m-d');

      try {
          $results = $analytics->data_ga->get($analytics_id, $lastWeek, $today,'ga:visits');
          echo '<b>Number of visits this week:</b> ';
          echo $results['totalsForAllResults']['ga:visits'];
      } catch(Exception $e) {
          echo 'There was an error : - ' . $e->getMessage();
      }

?>
```

**Error**

```
There was an error : - Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: 'Protection: 1; mode=block Server: GSE Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic Transfer-Encoding: chunked { "error" : "invalid_grant" }'
```

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572077/google-service-account-example-returns-error-refreshing-the-oauth2-token-err

Answer (score 2):

I just got my analytics working with a service account yesterday - so I might be able to help.  From the console, https://console.developers.google.com/project, you can select your project and go to "APIS & AUTH".  Make sure analytics API is turned on.  And make sure you have service account "credentials".  Make sure to grant the service account email address permissions for your google analytics property.  You will also need to get the P12 key file for your service account and provide that key file on your server.  I actually use the complete file path for my $key_file_location variable.

I used this code on GitHub: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/service-account.php

The example is for the Books API - so just replace "Books" with "Analytics" and "books" with "analytics".  Fill in your service account credentials and remember to add your service account email to your google analytics property.

Answer (score 0):

You just confirm your service account email id is associated wit [google analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) account, and have proper permissions.

The second thing you make sure .P12 file is generated after compiling above step.